# Heroku server upload

Tags: android, heroku, uploading

Hi Everyone is it possible to upload data(images, videos, text) to heroku server via android.  I am creating an app for android in which i want to put the functionality of uploading data to heroku. Is it  possible??? If yes then how can i do that . Please provide some material anything that could help me.
THanks

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is read-only. Your application will need to use a third-party service like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com) or use a CDN like Amazon's S3 service.

For more information about Heroku's filesystem, visit 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem